# Right way to map keys of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Please guide me with the right way to get this:

Supose i have this data:

```
 var personnel = [
  {
   id: 5,
   name: "Luke Skywalker",
   pilotingScore: 98,
   shootingScore: 56,
   isForceUser: true,
  },
  {
   id: 82,
   name: "Sabine Wren",
   pilotingScore: 73,
   shootingScore: 99,
   isForceUser: false,
 },
 {
   id: 22,
   name: "Zeb Orellios",
   pilotingScore: 20,
   shootingScore: 59,
   isForceUser: false,
 }
];
```

and i need the result as this:

```
 { 5: "Luke Skywalker", 82:"Sabine Wren", 22: "Zeb Orellios"}
```

i have tried with map i also tried foreach, i can not get some approach.

thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `reduce`

```
personnel.reduce((acc, i) => Object.assign(acc, {[i.id]: i.name}), {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var res = {};
for (p of personnel) {
    res[p.id] = p.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.map()` to create an array of `[id, name]` pairs, and convert to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const personnel = [{"id":5,"name":"Luke Skywalker","pilotingScore":98,"shootingScore":56,"isForceUser":true},{"id":82,"name":"Sabine Wren","pilotingScore":73,"shootingScore":99,"isForceUser":false},{"id":22,"name":"Zeb Orellios","pilotingScore":20,"shootingScore":59,"isForceUser":false}];

const result = Object.fromEntries(personnel.map(o => [o.id, o.name]));

console.log(result);
```